# how do i create new OU in Active Directory using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in .net 3.5 or 4

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, active-directory, ldap

to create & find users & groups in Active Directory i've been using this code:
http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/
that is using the new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace that was introduced in .net 3.5...

i'd like to add a method that creates a new OU (if the OU doesnt exist already) using the newest technology with .net 3.5 or 4.0 (and not using the old System.DirectoryServices)

any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx#S1) specialy the architecture here under and [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299745.aspx) article, accountManagement is for users groups and computers (security principals).

[image: Active Directory Architecture]

For `organizationalUnit`, you can use `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` here is an example :

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

...

/* Connection to Active Directory
 */
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/ou=Monou,dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "PWD");

DirectorySearcher ouSrc = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
ouSrc.Filter = "(OU=TheNewOU)";
ouSrc.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
SearchResult srOU = ouSrc.FindOne();
if (srOU == null)
{
  /* OU Creation
   */
  DirectoryEntry anOU = deBase.Children.Add("OU=TheNewOU", "organizationalUnit");
  anOU.Properties["description"].Value = "The description you want";
  anOU.CommitChanges();
}
```

Don't forget to use `using(){}` directive

Comment: I think you can use the `PrincipalContext` to retreive the `Container` value.

Comment: but can i check if the OU exists ?
and can i add a new OU ?

if not, i do i take the principal context and create a DirectoryEntery object from it's properties?